# Why isn't my code creating a grandchild process via fork/ C?

Tags: c, fork

I thought I created the grandchild process and tried to call the id to confirm the different between it and the parent process/ first child process id. Anyone have insight on this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) {
  int pid;
  int pid2;
  pid = fork();
  wait(NULL);
  
  switch(pid)
  {
    case -1:
      printf("Error: Not able to fork process");
      break;
    case 0:
      printf("This appears to be the child process. The id might be %d \n", getpid());
     pid2 = fork();
     printf("Grandchild ID? %d\n", getpid());
      break;
    default:
      //printf("Are you my Dad?\n");
      printf("Are you my Dad? %d \n",getpid() );
  
      break;
  }
  //printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give the exact expected result vs actual result. For the second `fork` call you are not distinguishing between the parent and the child process.

Comment: Your code is probably `fork()`ing just fine. You just get two `Grandchild` print outs. One with the child pid and one with the grandchild pid.  Check [this version](https://godbolt.org/z/vbfM6bdh4)

Comment: Why are you calling `wait()` before checking the return value of `fork()`?

Comment: @Shawn I had put the wait at a line checking if process was a child process, but I think I did incorrectly since the output was inconsistent. I tried moving the wait where it is now and I get consistent output. However, it seems to me that my second fork isn't creating a child process from the first child process.

Comment: @kaylum I thought my code would print the following except show the unique id for the grandchild process, but it looks the same as the child process. I ```This appears to be the child process. The id might be 41 
Grandchild ID? 41
Are you my Dad? 40    ```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get insight into what goes on is to more fully instrument the code, printing more information.  Here's an adaptation of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%5d: initial process (PPID %d)\n", getpid(), getppid());

    int pid = fork();

    printf("%5d: after fork (PPID %d)\n", getpid(), getppid());

    int status;
    int corpse = wait(&status);
    if (corpse > 0)
        printf("%5d: child %d died with status 0x%.4X\n", getpid(), corpse, status);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "%5d: wait failed (%d: %s)\n", getpid(), errno, strerror(errno));

    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        fprintf(stderr, "%5d: Error: Not able to fork process (%d: %s)\n",
                getpid(), errno, strerror(errno));
        break;
    case 0:
        printf("%5d: Child process\n", getpid());
        int pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 < 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "%5d: failed to fork grandchild (PPID %d)\n", getpid(), getppid());
        else if (pid2 > 0)
            printf("%5d: grandchild has PID %d\n", getpid(), pid2);
        else
            printf("%5d: I am the grandchild (PPID %d)\n", getpid(), getppid());
        break;
    default:
        // printf("Are you my Dad?\n");
        printf("%5d: child PID %d\n", getpid(), pid);
        break;
    }
    printf("%5d: Exiting (PPID %d)\n", getpid(), getppid());
    return 0;
}
```

Note how the messages are prefixed uniformly with the current PID, obtained by calling `getpid()` each time.  Note, too, that information is printed after each system call.

An example run (source code `gk89.c`, program `gk89`):

```
$ ./gk89
54711: initial process (PPID 2943)
54711: after fork (PPID 2943)
54712: after fork (PPID 54711)
54712: wait failed (10: No child processes)
54712: Child process
54712: grandchild has PID 54713
54712: Exiting (PPID 54711)
54713: I am the grandchild (PPID 54712)
54711: child 54712 died with status 0x0000
54711: child PID 54712
54711: Exiting (PPID 2943)
54713: Exiting (PPID 1)
$
```

Note that the grandchild is created (PID 54713), initially with parent PID 54712, but by the time it exits, its parent has died, so it reports its PPID as 1 when it exits.  It has been inherited by the system process, usually called `init`, that mainly waits for orphaned processes (which it automatically inherits) to die.

The sequence shown is subject to the whims of the system scheduling the processes.  It so happened that the grandchild's exit message was printed before the shell prompt (`$`), but that is not guaranteed.  OTOH, the initial process will not exit until the child process has exited because of the `wait()` call.