# How do I better implement functions like wait to control the order in which my created processes run?

Tags: c, fork, wait

I just read about the wait function in my textbook, however, I'm having a hard time implementing it to control the order of my processes. The outcome here is as follows:
Child ID:      141
Grandchild ID: 142
Dad ID:        140

I'd like to switch the grandchild line with the childline. Any recommended resources to learn about this desired type of control? The posted learning material barely goes over this, despite asking me to do an assignment entirely based on creating multiple processes and requesting a specific order to their execution and output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) {
  
  int pid;
  int pid2;
  pid = fork();
  
int aids;

  wait(NULL);

  switch(pid)
  {
    case -1:
      printf("Error: Not able to fork process");
      break;
    case 0:
      
      printf("Child ID:      %d \n", getpid());
     
      pid2 = fork();
      if(pid2==0) printf("Grandchild ID: %d\n", getpid());

      else if(pid2 != -1) wait(NULL); // wait for grandchild
      break;
    default:
   
      printf("Dad ID:        %d \n",getpid() );
      break;
  }
  //printf("Hello World    %d\n", getpid());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `wait()` just waits for a child to exit. You can't use it to control the order that they run.

Comment: Unless you're creating multiple children from the same parent. You can wait for child 1 to finish before starting child 2. But you can't wait for a grandchild.

Comment: You need some IPC (inter-process communication) mechanism to control the running of multiple processes. Something like pipes, where the children each wait on a pipe, and the boss sends messages down the pipes saying "you...now you..."

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Is the wait function better suited for handling a couple of processes while IPC is ideal for multiple process control?

Comment: `Is the wait function better suited for handling a couple of processes while IPC is ideal for multiple process control?` `wait()` is for waiting for a child to exit. IPC is for communicating between processes. Hammer is for hammering nails. Sure you can say that hammers are for building houses or hitting people - intention really depends on how you use it. They are just tools. `Any recommended resources...` is offtopic for stackoverflow. But surely you can type in google "IPC Linux tutorial" and you'll find many links.

Comment: This question is closely related to, but slightly different from, [Why isn't my code creating a grandchild process via `fork()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69005440/why-isnt-my-code-creating-a-grandchild-process-via-fork-c/69015610#69015610)

Comment: If you want the child ID message to appear after the grandchild message, don't print the child ID message until after the grandchild has exited.  In other words, move `printf("Child ID:      %d \n", getpid());` after the `switch`, and only execute it if `pid2` is strictly positive (not zero, not negative).  Note that printing spaces before newlines is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69021304/how-do-i-better-implement-functions-like-wait-to-control-the-order-in-which-my-c/69023949#comment121989387_69021304), you simply need to print the child ID after you know the grandchild has exited, which is when the `wait()` returns in the child process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid = fork();
    int pid2;

    wait(NULL);

    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Not able to fork process\n");
        break;

    case 0:
        pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == 0)
            printf("Grandchild ID: %d\n", getpid());
        else if (pid2 != -1)
        {
            wait(NULL);               // wait for grandchild
            printf("Child ID:      %d\n", getpid());
        }
        break;

    default:
        printf("Dad ID:        %d\n", getpid());
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output (source file `gk29.c`, executable `gk29`):

```
$ gk29
Grandchild ID: 65860
Child ID:      65859 
Dad ID:        65858 
$ gk29
Grandchild ID: 65863
Child ID:      65862 
Dad ID:        65861 
$
```